# Obtener siguiente domingo con java calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Estoy buscando la forma de a partir de la fecha actual encontrar el siguiente domingo pero no hay forma. He creado este código a partir de otros vistos por internet pero no me funciona. Alguna idea? Gracias

```
 Calendar notiDiumenge = Calendar.getInstance();
 notiDiumenge.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
 String dataSel = notiDiumenge.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + notiDiumenge.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + notiDiumenge.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: Antes que eso debes buscar el día siguiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo hice así:

Primero me aseguré de obtener le nombre del día... porque no se me ocuriró otra forma XD

```
today.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, new Locale("ES", "MX"))
```

Luego al ver que salía `dom.` obviamente de domingo porque lo puse en castellanmo de méxico que es mi país ( Obvii ) lo comparé con cadena apra asegurarme que si hoy era domingo ya hubiera terminado.

Luego mientras no fuera le iba a agregar un día usando el método add:

```
today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

y ya, lo extraje a un método para que se viera bonito :3

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions412507;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar getNextSunday = getNextSunday();
        Calendar notiDiumenge = getNextSunday;

        String dataSel = notiDiumenge.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"
                + notiDiumenge.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-"
                + notiDiumenge.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(dataSel);
    }

    private static Calendar getNextSunday() {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        while (!today.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, new Locale("ES", "MX")).equals("dom.")) {
            today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        return today;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @ruslan-lópez me va perfecto. Solo he modificado el metodo por el número de la semana para facilitar el código:
    private Calendar getNextSunday() {
        Calendar avui = Calendar.getInstance();
        int nD=avui.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        while (nD!=1) {
            avui.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            nD = avui.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        }
        return avui;
    }

Comment: Seria mas simple si se utilizara `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY` para evaluar el día de esta forma no dependes del `Locale` y la solución seria mas simple.